# Why does screen is not interactive when using react-native-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I started using `react-native-navigation` library. When applied my screens to `Navigation` object, the screen is not interactive anymore, like clicking on button.

I've reduced my code to minimum code:

`index.js`:

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation'
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeScreen'
Navigation.registerComponent(`WelcomeScreen`, () => WelcomeScreen)

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            stack: {
                id: 'AppStack',
                children: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'WelcomeScreen'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

WelcomeScreen.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Button, View} from 'react-native'

type Props = {};
export default class WelcomeScreen extends Component<Props> {
    handleClick = () => {
        console.log('Button Clicked')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="Click" onPress={this.handleClick} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The button is not showing any animation of click and of course no log on console appears.

What am I doing wrong?